# Can I perform update inside PL/SQL function?

Tags: oracle, plsql, stored-functions

is it possible, to update table within function? Because mine does not do anything..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION rep_ort(id INT, status VARCHAR2, end_date DATE, explanation VARCHAR2) 
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
UPDATE reports
SET 
id = id,
status = status,
end_date = end_date,
explanation = explanation;
commit;
RETURN 'Updated';
END;

select rep_ort('5','Closed','2021-01-12 17:30','Client fault') from dual;
```

Comment: Probably unrelated: Shouldn't you use the id in the WHERE clause instead of in the SET clause?

Comment: Maybe, but how should it look like?
where id = id?

Comment: WHERE id = id does nothing...

Comment: Use a different parameter name than the column name

Comment: If you don't use the `id` in the WHERE clause, it will update every record in the table. I assume `id` is the primary key and you want to update a specific record, not all records in the table.

Comment: You should use a procedure. When you make an UPDATE (or any other DML) in the function then you cannot use it like `select rep_ort(...) from dual`, use `begin ret:= rep_ort(...); end;`

Comment: Parameter `end_date` is a `DATE` data type, thus you should pass also a `DATE` value instead of a **string**. User for example `TO_DATE('2021-01-12 17:30','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')` Similar for `id` which is a number, not a string.

Comment: Before running the update in a  procedure, try running the same SQL from SQL plus or another tool and see if you are updating any values, since you dont have a WHERE clause it looks like you want to update all the rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yours is doing nothing because you named parameters with the same name as columns, so you're just updating the whole table to the same values.

Rename parameters and - maybe - include `WHERE` clause.

Although you *can* do it, procedures are meant to be used for such a purpose.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION rep_ort
  (p_id INT, p_status VARCHAR2, p_end_date DATE, p_explanation VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
  UPDATE reports
  SET
   id          = p_id,
   status      = p_status,
   end_date    = p_end_date,
   explanation = p_explanation;

  commit;
  RETURN 'Updated';
END;
```

Comment: Man, that was it!! I needed to use WHERE clause, but that was it. That's lit, thank you very much. <3

Comment: @Trapist_e: Please mark the answer as solved.

Comment: The WHERE may have solved your immediate problem, but I'd reiterate the comment of @wernfried Domscheit that you should not be using a _function_ for this.  The intended purpose of a _function_ is to return a value, not to be modifying data.